# Android OpenConnection() to ntlm

Tags: android, ntlm

With newer android versions coming out the old ntlm methods and classes for android are now deprecated. Android says to use openconnection but I can't find a thing about how to use openconnection to connect to a site that uses ntlm based authentication. Does any one know how to do this with API 22+?

Comment: you figure any of this out?

Comment: I'm very interested in this also. I can't find a example where a class is not deprecated and even then I can't authenticate.

Comment: No, we never did. It's still a mystery how any of this works.